# How do I create a clan?

Tags: realm-of-empires

I'm wondering how to create a clan in Realm of Empires (The Facebook game)

What building do I need, and at what level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any special building to create a clan.

just click on the Clan icon on top right of the screen

[image]